# Default entry for /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I accidentally removed everything inside my laptop's `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Now it does not find any WiFi network/SSID

I Tried to change to this but it still has problem:

```
auto lo
Iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then I do

```
$ ifup wlan0
```

But it gets stuck and prints the following line forever:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue with `/etc/network/interfaces`, wireless will require the addition of the network you intend to connect to and any encryption details. I suggest:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid mynetwork
wpa-psk 0123456789
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting network-manager after adding back the file content?

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `/etc/network/interface` the following code:

`auto lo`

> `iface lo inet loopback`

Then save the file and run the command:

`sudo restart network-manager` - as el_tigro stated.

This should reactivate the network interface and allow you to connect to the internet again.